# Dataflowで使用しているSDKバージョンが非推奨とされた場合の対応方法を知りたい

Tags: java, google-cloud, google-drive-sdk

現在使用しているSDKバージョンが**Apache Beam SDK for Java 2.14.0**で非推奨になっているのですが、いつまでにアップグレードした方が良いのでしょうか。また、どのようにアップグレードした方が良いのかもお聞きしたいです。

**使用中のDataflowのSDKバージョン:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「SDKバージョンがApache Beam SDK for Java 2.14.0で非推奨になっている」というのは、どこで見た情報ですか？

Comment: GCPのウェブサイトに記載しておりました。
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/sdk-version-support-status?_ga=2.132798861.-2093673950.1596768702

Answer (score 0):

> いつまでにアップグレードした方が良いのでしょうか。

既にサポート対象外になっている（期限が切れている）ので、「いつまでに」という期限は無いですね。セキュリティなどの要件次第ですが、サポートが不要であれば、そのまま使ってもいいのではないしょうか。

> どのようにアップグレードした方が良いのかもお聞きしたいです。

そのページの1つ下のセクション「[サポートされていない SDK を使用する](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/using-unsupported-sdks)」に対応（アップグレードなど）の方法が書いてあるようです（Mavenであれば`pom.xml`内の`<version>`タグを書き換える）。